# Android: Why my custom camera's quality is not as high as system camera?

Tags: android, camera

Android: Why my custom camera's quality is not as high as system camera ?
Is anyone can tell me how to make the picture more clear ,or how to set up the camera parameters? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CameraPreview class of [this](https://github.com/pikanji/CameraPreviewSample) project. It also maintains aspect ratio.